# How to split spaces in strings (cross-browser safe)

Tags: javascript

What is the best cross-browser practice to split spaces in a string with Javascript?
I tried `theString.split(" ")` but i am having issues with IE and Chrome/Safari.

**Update**

Here's the js code. IE/Chrome throw error at line: 61

http://pastie.org/1151951

Comment: Errors in the first line i'm using split, both in Webkit and IE. Chrome indicates "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" while IE8 shows "Invalid character".

Comment: Is the string really a string? Because this should work. Perhaps post a bit more code, this is a really strange anomaly.

Comment: typeof(theString) returns a string. And i'm using the value of a <span> tag -- theString = $("span").text(); -> returns "8 pm".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid having empty parts, split with the help of a regex:

```
var parts = theString.split(/ +/);
```

Optionally, trim string before splitting.

```
var parts = theString.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").split(/ +/);
```

Comment: I'm still getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" in Chrome.

Comment: @fuSi0N: That's a syntax error somewhere else and has nothing to do with splitting a string.

Comment: Definitely has something to do with split(). As soon as i remove the first split(), it throws the same error at line: 83. Any ideas?

Comment: @fuSi0N: You have a broken UTF-8 character in your .js file right between the `Date.split(/ +/)` and the `;`. If you are interested, open the .js file in a hex editor and see for yourself. To fix it, just delete the entire line and rewrite it from scratch, instead of copy/pasting it from the clipboard all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Below seems to work fine for me

> someText.split(/\s/)

With whitespace removal

> someText.split(/\s+/)